# Read spec chain in a custom rpc method

Tags: rpc, json-rpc

I know that some RPC query exist to get informations like :
system_properties
system_chain
system_chainType

But I would like to have all of them in a same custom call.
How I can access to those informations ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You want to create a custom RPC which does those 3 queries at once?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi yes that's it. do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: You either need to make 3 RPC calls, or write your own custom RPC in Substrate which does all three at once. There is no "trick" here.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do : write my one custom RPC but I dont know how to get those substrate informations given by system_syncState or system_properties ?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

All of those RPCs can be found here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/rpc/src/system/mod.rs

```rust
impl<B: traits::Block> SystemApi<B::Hash, <B::Header as HeaderT>::Number> for System<B> {

    // -- snip --

    fn system_properties(&self) -> Result<sc_chain_spec::Properties> {
        Ok(self.info.properties.clone())
    }

    // -- snip --

    fn system_sync_state(&self) -> Receiver<SyncState<<B::Header as HeaderT>::Number>> {
        let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();
        let _ = self.send_back.unbounded_send(Request::SyncState(tx));
        Receiver(rx)
    }

    // -- snip --
}
```

These are then implemented in the node's RPC configuration:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/rpc/src/lib.rs

```rust
io.extend_with(SystemApi::to_delegate(FullSystem::new(client.clone(), pool, deny_unsafe)));
```

Comment: What I dont understand is that we declare instantiate  with `pub fn new(   info: SystemInfo,   send_back: TracingUnboundedSender<Request<B>>,   deny_unsafe: DenyUnsafe,  ) -> Self {   System { info, send_back, deny_unsafe }  }  ` and we pass `client.clone()` for info in `FullSystem::new(client.clone()`

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to open a new question?

Comment: I opened a new one

Comment: this one : https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3698/get-system-info-in-custom-rpc-call