# Get System info in custom RPC call

Tags: rpc, json-rpc

Hello I would like to be able to call

```
fn system_name(&self) -> RpcResult<String> {
    Ok(self.info.impl_name.clone())
}
```

inside a custom rpc call
our custom rpc call is implemented like that:

```
io.extend_with(ApiServer::to_delegate(Api::new(
    client.clone(),
    pool.clone(),
    graph,
    Some(aureum_node_runtime::TransactionConverter),
    network.clone(),
    signers,
    overrides.clone(),
    backend.clone(),
    is_authority,
    block_data_cache.clone(),
)));
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you running into? Please review: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello @ShawnTabrizi, I searched how to add info property in the implement function `io.extend_with(ApiServer::to_delegate(Api::new(
    client.clone(),
    pool.clone(),
    graph,
    Some(aureum_node_runtime::TransactionConverter),
    network.clone(),
    signers,
    overrides.clone(),
    backend.clone(),
    is_authority,
    block_data_cache.clone(),
)));` I cant find a way how to access `info` in my Api methods. thank you.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi an idea? thank you

Comment: No not really. It is not clear to me what you want to do. I cannot even read the code you have copied into your comment. You need to please review how to ask a proper question here on the forum.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I just want to use this method `Ok(self.info.impl_name.clone())` in my custom rpc code